# Nested matching using java script regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group

I have a long text which is a multi line and need to extract the text as shown.

They must be extracted in such a way that "It starts from second bracket" the text content may vary

Ends as shown in the image.

So a regex based on text isn't useful rather. How do I match just by the position of brackets.

The highlighted text is the expected output

[image]

Sample text:

(ti,ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter) near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman* near/5 Access) OR (Access* p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0 flex)) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxH) OR ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR Coulter*LH)) OR ((Ortho p/0 Clinical P/1 Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros* p/1 System*) OR (VITROS* p/1 ECiQ) OR ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION) OR (ORTHO p/1 AutoVue*)) OR ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR HemosIL OR ACLTOP OR (ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEM*OPL) OR ((Radiometer near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0 FLEX) OR (ABL?? p/0 FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) OR StatStrip OR (STAT p/0 PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1 Prime) OR STATPROFILE*) OR (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0 Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT))) and (ud(>20170101)) (see attachment)

(ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter) near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman* near/5 Access) OR (Access* p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0 flex)) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxH) OR ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR Coulter*LH)) OR ((Ortho p/0 Clinical P/1 Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros* p/1 System*) OR (VITROS* p/1 ECiQ) OR ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION) OR (ORTHO p/1 AutoVue*)) OR ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR HemosIL OR ACLTOP OR (ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEM*OPL) OR ((Radiometer near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0 FLEX) OR (ABL?? p/0 FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) OR StatStrip OR (STAT p/0 PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1 Prime) OR STATPROFILE*) OR (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0 Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT))) and (ud(>20180101)) (sample)

(ti(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter) near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman* near/5 Access) OR (Access* p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0 flex)) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxH) OR ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR Coulter*LH)) OR ((Ortho p/0 Clinical P/1 Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros* p/1 System*) OR (VITROS* p/1 ECiQ) OR ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION) OR (ORTHO p/1 AutoVue*)) OR ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR HemosIL OR ACLTOP OR (ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEM*OPL) OR ((Radiometer near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0 FLEX) OR (ABL?? p/0 FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) OR StatStrip OR (STAT p/0 PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1 Prime) OR STATPROFILE*) OR (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0 Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT))) and (ud(>20180101)) (sample)

Comment: I don't understand what the expected output will be

Comment: The highlighted is expected output

Comment: I downvoted because [no reasonable attempt at solving the problem has been provided by you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I do not know it. Why will I ask then?

Comment: If you have made any attempt at finding a solution, please post it, but it seems like no effort on your side has been done to find a solution.

We are not a code writing service. Please make an attempt at solving it yourself before coming to us

Comment: found for (?<=\().+?(?=\)) .* attachment\)

Answer (score 0):

A working solution might be:

```
 function getSecondParenthesis( text )
 {
     var out = "";
     var nCont;
     var nFound = 0;

     // jump the first parenthesis, until the second one
     nCont = 0; 
     while( nCont < text.length && nFound < 2 )
     {
         if( text.charAt(nCont) == '(' )
             ++nFound;
         ++nCont;
     } // nCont < text.length

     // just copy text jumping over 
     // opening and closing parenthesis, 
     // until reach the 0 count again
     do
     {
         if( text.charAt(nCont) == '(' ) 
             ++nFound; 
         if( text.charAt(nCont) == ')' ) 
             --nFound;
         if( nFound != 0 )
             out += text.charAt(nCont);  
         ++nCont; 
     }
     while( nCont < text.length && nFound != 0 );

     return out;

 }
```